# Aggregate query doesnt work properly with dates $lte & $gte

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

if date range is 2 days, like
startDate = 2023-11-26
endDate = 2023-11-27
all working fine, when dates are equal, campaigns array is empty, how to make this $gte and $lte comparsion work? Im sure that data for this day is present and problem is in aggregate part

```
async getCampaigns(query, res) {
console.log(query);

try {
  let { offset = 0, limit = 30, startDate, endDate } = query;

  const startDateString = startDate;
  endDate = new Date(endDate);
  offset = parseInt(offset);
  limit = Math.min(
    parseInt(limit),
    await this.campaignModel.countDocuments(),
  );
  startDate = startDate
    ? new Date(startDate)
    : new Date(endDate.getTime() - 14 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
  
  if (isNaN(offset) || isNaN(limit)) {
    throw new BadRequestError('Invalid offset or limit');
  }
  const dates = getAllDatesBetween(`${startDateString}/${endDate}`);
  const campaigns = await this.campaignModel.aggregate([
    { $addFields: { datesArray: { $objectToArray: '$dates' } } },
    { $unwind: '$datesArray' },
    {
      $match: {
        'datesArray.k': {
          $gte: startDate.toISOString(),
          $lte: endDate.toISOString(),
        },
      },
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: '$_id',
        totalCost: { $sum: '$datesArray.v.cost' },
        document: { $first: '$$ROOT' },
      },
    },
    { $sort: { totalCost: -1 } },
    { $skip: offset },
    { $limit: limit },
    {
      $replaceRoot: {
        newRoot: {
          $mergeObjects: ['$document', { totalCost: '$totalCost' }],
        },
      },
    },
  ]);
  console.log(campaigns);
...
} catch (error) {
  throw new InternalServerError('Internal Server Error');
}}
```

UPDATE: Added sample docs as requested
input docs(campaign):

```
{
            "_id": "666",
            "trafficSourceName": "bla",
            "name": "Sorry",
            "keyword": "What Happens At A Cremation Australia",
            "status": "active",
            "limitsFilter": {
                "limitType": "budget_limits",
                "dailyLimit": 7500,
                "overallLimit": 100000000,
                "splitDailyLimitEvenly": 0
            },
            dates: {
                "2023-11-25": {}, 
                "2023-11-26": {}, 
                "2023-11-27": {}
            }
            },{
            "_id": "444",
            "trafficSourceName": "bla",
            "name": "Sorry",
            "keyword": "What Happens At A Cremation United States",
            "status": "active",
            "limitsFilter": {
                "limitType": "budget_limits",
                "dailyLimit": 20000,
                "overallLimit": 100000000,
                "splitDailyLimitEvenly": 0
            },                 dates: {
                "2023-11-25": {}, 
                "2023-11-26": {}, 
                "2023-11-27": {}
            }
            }
```

Comment: Are you comparing ISOStrings of dates to date fields? Type mismatch is one of the common mistakes that will result in query failure.

Comment: @ray, as he is doing `{ $objectToArray: '$dates' }` it seems to be even worse. Looks like the date string is used as key. I would say, it's a design flaw.

Comment: Can you `console.log(startDate.toISOString())` and then `console.log(endDate.toISOString())` just before you run the query. If they are exactly the same you won't get any campaigns in the array because nothing is between the exact same time.

Comment: This really depends on what the documents look like.  If the fieldname in the document is "2023-11-26" and the start date is also "2023-11-26", `new Date("2023-11-26").toISOString()` will be "2023-11-26T00:00:00.000Z", so the `$gte: startDate.toISOString()` will not match.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this with just adding startDate as key of dates. So if the key is present - this satisfy condition, I used date comparsions with ISOString because this is what written in MongoDB Docs.

```
const campaigns = await this.campaignModel.aggregate([
    { $addFields: { datesArray: { $objectToArray: '$dates' } } },
    { $unwind: '$datesArray' },
    {
      $match: startDate.toISOString().split('T')[0] != endDate.toISOString().split('T')[0] ? {
        'datesArray.k': 
        {
          $gte: startDate.toISOString(),
          $lte: endDate.toISOString(),  
        },
      } : {
         'datesArray.k': startDate.toISOString().split('T')[0]
      },
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: '$_id',
        totalCost: { $sum: '$datesArray.v.cost' },
        document: { $first: '$$ROOT' },
      },
    },
    { $sort: { totalCost: -1 } },
    { $skip: offset },
    { $limit: limit },
    {
      $replaceRoot: {
        newRoot: {
          $mergeObjects: ['$document', { totalCost: '$totalCost' }],
        },
      },
    },
  ]);
```

Comment: If there any way to speed up this query, please share with me :)

Comment: Please edit your original question to show us 1 or 2 sample input docs and show us the desired output.   There is too much going on in your example e.g. the grouping on `cost`.

Also, MongoDB does *not* recommend comparing date strings.

Comment: grouping on cost is for sorting, first campaigns will be campaigns with most cost on them